# Splitting toolbox feature dataZoom into components

Tags: javascript, grafana, echarts, monaco-editor, toolbox

Having trouble splitting dataZoom into separate components, idea is [5] will have different configuration from the rest. Split works fine outside toolbox, doesn't work inside of toolbox.

There is a [5] index, which is not zoomed with datazoom outside toolbox, but it is zoomed when using datazoom inside toolbox

Toolbox datazoom should work as datazoom outside it.

```
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
      yAxisIndex: 'none',
      xAxisIndex: [0, 1, 2, 3],
    },
    {
      type: 'inside',
      yAxisIndex: 'none',
      xAxisIndex: [4],
    }
  ],

  toolbox: {
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    itemSize: 40,
    feature: {
      dataZoom: [
        {
          id: '1',
          type: 'inside',
          yAxisIndex: 'none',
          xAxisIndex: [0, 1, 2, 3],
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          type: 'inside',
          yAxisIndex: 'none',
          xAxisIndex: [4],
        }],
      restore: {},
      saveAsImage: {},
    },
  },
```

So far I've tried moving around blocks, giving id, defining zoomconfig and giving it to feature.datazoom

Edit:

[No zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkTrk.png)

[Zoomed with mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEJ5O.png)

[Zoomed with Toolbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zK1E.png)

As you can see where it's zoomed in with Toolbox, days are also zoomed in, I am trying to achieve that, when toolbox is used, [5] or day names on xaxis do not get zoomed. Like when it's zoomed in using mouse.

Comment: I dont think you can add multiple instances of toolbox dataZoom. Also, it is not quite clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Can you add an image or a more elaborate explanation?

Comment: Does it not change the meaning of the plot if the xAxis is not zoomed? I guess you could make an xAxis for the plot which is not shown and use it for zooming while keeping another one visable for labeling. Would also be helpful to see your whole chart option. For what are you using 5 xAxes?

Comment: 5 weeks of data [0-4], and last is day labels for each of the day [5]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yUCq.png, so far i haven't found an option for day label to precisely show values when zoomed in, so for now i'm searching for a way to hide day labels when zoomed in :D

Comment: for example i've zoomed in here, and you can see the label now is incorrect https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwifw.png, when zoomed out it's all correct. The normal datazoom is working fine, I can hide it there, but I want to make it work in toolbox.datazoom, so we have the option to click the button to use drag zoom. Issue with normal datazoom is, I have no knowledge and couldn't find a solution to add drag zoom without a usage of a button. Zooming with mousewheel or key+mouse wheel could be a good option, but I've been asked to stay away from mousewheel zoom :D

Comment: It sounds to me like you are making it more complicated than it needs to be. If I understand you correctly [`xAxis.type = 'time'`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.type) should be the correct approach for your use case.  Maybe together with [`axisLabel.formatter`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.formatter) and/or [`minInterval`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.minInterval).

Comment: You could also try and listen to the [datazoom event](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.datazoom) and adjust the axis formatting depending on the interval size.

Comment: Thanks! Will try to play around with datazoom event!